# How to select random dropdown in angularjs application in selenium using java

Tags: angularjs, selenium, select, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm learning automation using Selenium. I'm testing angularjs application. How do I write a java code to select random options from a dropdown

**Html:**

```
<select ng-model="attribute" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-required="draftstatus !== 'Incomplete' &amp;&amp; isrequired" ng-show="isrequired" ng-change="change" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" required="required" xpath="1" style="">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <!-- ngRepeat: option in collection -->
    <option ng-repeat="option in collection" ng-selected="option === attribute" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in collection -->
    <option ng-repeat="option in collection" ng-selected="option === attribute" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="Mayo">Mayo</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in collection -->
    <option ng-repeat="option in collection" ng-selected="option === attribute" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="Orange">Orange</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in collection -->
    <option ng-repeat="option in collection" ng-selected="option === attribute" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in collection -->
    <option ng-repeat="option in collection" ng-selected="option === attribute" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="Utah">Utah</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in collection -->
    <option ng-repeat="option in collection" ng-selected="option === attribute" class="ng-binding ng-scope" value="Mt.Titlis">Mt. Titlis</option>
    <!-- end ngRepeat: option in collection -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to treat drop down as normal element. `select` class will not work here. click on dropdown element then option list will open then click one of the option element of your choice

to open dropdown  -

```
By dropdownLoc  =  By.xpath(".//option[text()='Please Select']/parent::select[@ng-model='attribute']");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
        dropdown = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(dropdownLoc));
dropdown.click();
```

click/select option addition to it you can pass dropdown values into xpath and can make it dynamic -

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//option[@value='Mayo']")))
```

Answer (score 0):

To *click* on a random option within the *dropdown* as the element is [Angular](https://angular.io/) element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement placeNames = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched' and @ng-model='attribute'][@ng-change='change' and @ng-show='isrequired']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched' and @ng-model='attribute'][@ng-change='change' and @ng-show='isrequired']/option[text()='Please Select']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located(By.xpath("//select[@class='ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched' and @ng-model='attribute'][@ng-change='change' and @ng-show='isrequired']//option")));
  Select pNames = new Select(placeNames);
  pNames.selectByVisibleText("Apple");
  ```